Querying GBQ table to.dataframe() function took too long to respond
I am loading the table from google bigquery in python, the code as follow
def read_bq(project_id, dataset_id, table_id, bigquery_client, size):

    query = f"""
        SELECT *
        FROM {project_id}.{dataset_id}.{table_id}
        WHERE extract_id < {size}
    """
    a  = time()
    query_job = bigquery_client.query(query)
    b = time()
    # Convert the result into a Pandas DataFrame
    c = time()
    df = query_job.to_dataframe()
    d = time()
    #df = pandas_gbq.read_gbq(query, credentials=set_credential(), dialect='standard', use_bqstorage_api=True)
    print(f"Time to read the data: {b-a}")
    print(f"Time to convert the data to dataframe: {d-c}")
    return df

and the result of both time as follow
Time to read the data: 1.9432220458984375
Time to convert the data to dataframe: 28.81800627708435

The dataset is about 200000 row, but I didn't expect it took so long to load these data since my full dataset is way more than this number. So I wonder is there more a efficient way to read google bigquery table in python. Or a faster method to convert the query object to DataFrame.

Take a look into BigQuery DataFrames lib: https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery-dataframes
